# Racing condition in android instant search implementation

Tags: android, multithreading, loopj, android-async-http

I am implementing instant search in an Android app which fetches the search results from REST services. I want to avoid the racing conditions when app fires multiple calls. Any idea on how to implements this? I am using AsyncHttpClient(loopj) for making n/w calls and cancel all the request before i fire a new one using `asyncCclient.cancelRequests(getApplicationContext(), true)` and I also use the delay of 250ms between user keystrokes to fire the search. But still in some scenarios racing is happening. Please help..